# Does the value of PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName change when installing app updates?

Tags: android, google-play

The [`PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) method is documented like this:

> Retrieve the package name of the application that installed a package. This identifies which market the package came from.

This makes sense for the initial install of the application, but what about updates? If the user updates an app from a different store than where they installed it from (or from an APK, manually), will this value change, or will it always show where the original installation happened from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getInstallerPackageName` method always returns the package of the installer that installed *the currently installed version* of the APK. This means that updating it from a different source than where the original installation happened from *will change this value*.

If you want to keep track of where the original installation happened from over the long term, you'll have to store that value yourself.